# playframework JsValue in HTML Template

Tags: html, json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to define a json object in the template with the JsValue of play (v2.2.2). The problem is, `"` is converted to `&quot;`

```
@(org: db.Tables.OrganizationRow)

@import models.format.EntityFormat._
@import play.api.libs.json.Json

<script  type="text/javascript">
    var org = @Json.toJson(org);
</script>
```

results in:

```
{&quot;id&quot;:16,&quot;userid&quot;:&quot; ... more data ... };
```

How I'm able to get the correct json in the scala html template?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define it as `Html` so it doesn't automatically get escaped.

```
var org = @Html(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(org)));
```

Comment: By the way, what is `@Javascript`,`@Txt` used for?They are in the same package with `@Html` but I think they simply do nothing.

Comment: @Renkai They're used if you're using a different type of template in the first place. For example, in a `views/foo.scala.js` you'd use `@JavaScript(bar)` to do raw (not-JS-escaped) output of the value `bar`. As the docs say: "If you want to output a raw content fragment, wrap it in the template content type" (i.e @Html for .html, @Javascript for .js)

Comment: This approach is correct for trusted data, but it is not secure in general (if any data is untrusted then an attacker can break out of the js context with "</script>" or "<!--", even with correct js escaping). See https://uploadcare.com/blog/vulnerability-in-html-design/ . There is not currently a completely secure escaping mechanism for this context supplied by Play.