# Bootstrapping JSON data into Scala PlayFramework templates

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Goal is to go from a Model/ViewModel written in Scala to raw JSON that can be bootstrapped into the view template so as to avoid making requests for the JSON data after the page load.

And example of what I've been playing around with but I haven't had much luck:

```
@(todos: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)
@import play.api.libs.json.Json

<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>...</body>

   <script>
      var todos = JSON.parse(' @Json.stringify(todos) ');
   </script>
</html>
```

Basically its spitting out a lot of quoted text to the effect of:

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;:&quot;294858e2-c9eb-4f50-9eac-47b257573d83&quot;}]
```

Haven't had much luck with Google or the PlayFramework docs so I'd love some help.

Comment: What's actually not working here?

Comment: By default the template engine will HTML quote your data, so try something like `@Html(Json.stringify(todos))` to render it verbatim. Look at the HTML output to verify. You might also need to fully-qualify the `JsValue` type of the `todos` parameter as `play.api.libs.json.JsValue` since AFAIK it's not a default template import.

Comment: @Mikesname you correctly guessed the problem. And your suggestion for using `@Html` worked perfectly. If you can post your suggestion as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [playframework JsValue in HTML Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309803/playframework-jsvalue-in-html-template)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Play template engine will escape any strings you render to HTML, which will thoroughly mangle your JSON.

To output it verbatim, do `@Html(Json.stringify(todos))`, as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplates#Escaping).